# How could I create a hosted database to store data from my iOS app?

Tags: swift, database

im în my first year of software developing. Im trying to create an iOS app where I will have some authenticate and other databases query to do. How could I create a hosted database that users could authenticate and retrieve different informations from it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at different MBaaS solutions (Mobile Backend as a Service), the most prominent of which are possibly:

- AWS Amplify
- Firebase (Google)
- Azure Mobile Apps

They provide very simple ways to create a complete and secure backend for Mobile and Web Apps with Authentication, APIs, Data Storage and others.